# pandas dataframe row change type

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, floating-accuracy

I'm dealing with a balance sheet which I've parsed into pandas using:

```
    table = xls_file.parse('Consolidated_Balance_Sheet')
    table.ix[:, 1]

    0         None
    1         None
    2      $ 3,029
    3         1989
    5         None
    6     $ 34,479
```

I'm trying to identify the rows with unicode and strip the $ sign and comma, converting to float.

```
    for row in table.ix[:, 1]:
        if isinstance(row, unicode):
            print type(row), row
            num = float(row.lstrip('$').replace(',',''))
            print num
            row = num
            print type(row), row
```

This produces the following output:

```
    <type 'unicode'> $ 3,029
    3029.0
    <type 'float'> 3029.0
    <type 'unicode'> $ 34,479
    34479.0
    <type 'float'> 34479.0
```

However, the value is unchanged when I check the table

```
    table.ix[2, 1]
    u'$ 3,029'
```

How can I correctly change the value to a float?

**EDIT**: Thanks for the two responses, I can reproduce those with no problem. However when I use the apply function to my case I get an 'unhashable type' error.

```
In [167]: thead = table.head()
In [168]: thead

Out[168]:
         Consolidated Balance Sheet (USD $)  Sep. 30, 2012  Dec. 31, 2011
    0    In Millions, unless otherwise specified     None    None
    1    Current assets                              None    None
    2    Cash and cash equivalents                   $ 3,029 $ 2,219
    3    Marketable securities - current             1989    1461
    4    Accounts receivable - net                   4409    3867

In [170]: def no_comma_or_dollar(num):
              if isinstance(num, unicode):
                  return float(num.lstrip('$').replace(',',''))
              else:
                  return num

          thead[:, 1] = thead[:, 1].apply(no_comma_or_dollar)
```

Produces the following:

```
 TypeError: unhashable type
```

I can't get my head around why as I'm not changing the keys, just the values. Is there another way to change the values in the dataframe?

**EDIT2**:

```
In [171]: thead.to_dict()
Out[171]: {u'Consolidated Balance Sheet (USD $)': {0: u'In Millions, unless otherwise specified',
  1: u'Current assets',
  2: u'Cash and cash equivalents',
  3: u'Marketable securities - current',
  4: u'Accounts receivable - net'},
 u'Dec. 31, 2011': {0: None, 1: None, 2: u'$ 2,219', 3: 1461.0, 4: 3867.0},
 u'Sep. 30, 2012': {0: None, 1: None, 2: u'$ 3,029', 3: 1989.0, 4: 4409.0}}
```

Comment: Could you post `thead.to_dict()` so we can (perhaps) reproduce the problem?

Comment: `thead.ix[:, 1] = thead.ix[:, 1].apply(no_comma_or_dollar)` or `thead.ix[:, 1:] = thead.ix[:, 1:].applymap(no_comma_or_dollar)` (for both) should work.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will now get my head down and read up on applymap!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just printing these and not [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)-ing them to the DataFrame, here's one way to do it:

Create a function to do the striping (if unicode) or leave it if already a number:

```
def no_comma_or_dollar(num):
    if isinstance(num, unicode):
        return float(num.lstrip('$').replace(',',''))
    else:
        return num

table[col_name] = table[col_name].apply(no_comma_or_dollar)
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[u'$1,000'], [200.]])

In [3]: df[0].apply(no_comma_or_dollar)
Out[3]: 
0    1000
1     200
Name: 0
```

Update:

With the `thread` which you give, I would be tempted to give a slightly lazier version of `no_comma_or_dollar` and [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
def no_comma_or_dollar2(num):
    try:
        return float(num.lstrip('$').replace(',',''))
    except: # if you can't strip/replace/convert just leave it
        return num

In [5]: thread.applymap(no_comma_or_dollar2)
Out[5]: 
        Consolidated Balance Sheet (USD $)  Dec. 31, 2011  Sep. 30, 2012
0  In Millions, unless otherwise specified            NaN            NaN
1                           Current assets            NaN            NaN
2                Cash and cash equivalents           2219           3029
3          Marketable securities - current           1461           1989
4                Accounts receivable - net           3867           4409
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, you're looking for the `apply` method:

```
In [33]: import pandas as pd

In [34]: table = pd.Series([None, u'$ 3,12', u'$ 4,5'])

In [35]: table
Out[35]: 
0      None
1    $ 3,12
2     $ 4,5

In [36]: def f(cell):
   ....:     if isinstance(cell, unicode):
   ....:         return float(cell.lstrip('$').replace(',',''))
   ....:     else:
   ....:         return cell
   ....:     

In [37]: table.apply(f)
Out[37]: 
0    NaN
1    312
2     45
```

This does create a new object. In order to store the new object instead of the old, do:

```
In [42]: table = table.apply(f)

In [43]: table
Out[43]: 
0    NaN
1    312
2     45
```